# near-alignment of PC scores and variable vector (biplot)

Tags: alignment, pca, biplot

Here is the screenshot of my PCA biplot. As is evident there is an alignment (although not perfect), of my PC scores and the variable vector . Is there any interpretation of this alignment?

[PCA biplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxVCv.png)

Ray

this is a question of graph interpreation, not a technical problem.